# Want to add Superscripts with TextView numbers using StringBuilder

Tags: java, android, kotlin

```java
public class SuperscriptFormatter {
    private static final String SUPERSCRIPT_REGEX = "(?<=\\b\\d{0,10})(st|nd|rd|th)(?=\\b)";
    private static final Pattern PATTERN = Pattern.compile(SUPERSCRIPT_REGEX);
    private static final float PROPORTION = 0.5f;

    private final SpannableStringBuilder stringBuilder;

    public SuperscriptFormatter (@NonNull SpannableStringBuilder stringBuilder) {
        this.stringBuilder = stringBuilder;
    }

    public void format(TextView textView) {
        CharSequence text = textView.getText();
        Matcher matcher = PATTERN.matcher(text);
        stringBuilder.clear();
        stringBuilder.append(text);
        while (matcher.find()) {
            int start = matcher.start();
            int end = matcher.end();
            createSuperscriptSpan(start, end);
        }
        textView.setText(stringBuilder);
    }

    private void createSuperscriptSpan(int start, int end) {
        SuperscriptSpan superscript = new SuperscriptSpan();
        RelativeSizeSpan size = new RelativeSizeSpan(PROPORTION);
        stringBuilder.setSpan(superscript, start, end, Spanned.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
        stringBuilder.setSpan(size, start, end, Spanned.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
    }
}
```

The problem is that I am unable to get those superscripts with a number.
I  am passing "1", "2" as text and `matcher.find()` returning false every time, I don't know what is going on either with the pattern or with my text.
I want 1st,2nd 3rd ... etc as text

Comment: If you want to display 1st , st as superscripts

Comment: @vimukthi actually I want to add superscripts for each no like for 21st, 22nd, 11th, 13th, random numbers .. etc till 500 approx

Comment: @vimukthiI I have to concat each no with its superscript

Comment: How do you set the text?

Comment: yes i have to concat st,nd,rd and th with random no's according to their pairs.

Comment: If you set String like this "21st, 22nd, 11th, 13th"

Answer (score 1):

In above code there  You have to set the text in your Activity class or .xml file in layout folder.

```
textView.setText( "21st, 22nd, 11th, 13th");
```

or xml file textview

```
android:text= "21st, 22nd, 11th, 13th"
```

like this there are no auto put superscript in there.

Comment: I appreciate your efforts but this is not what I wanted, I have given you the example only "21st, 22nd, 11th, 13th" that I wanted to add superscripts for random numbers, so only those no's will not be there every time, No's can be in the range of 1 till 999

Answer (score 0):

i have written my own logic for adding superscript with numbers.
Here i am working on RecyclerView adapter using kotlin, i am sharing code for onBindViewHolder .

```
    var stringBuilder: SpannableStringBuilder = SpannableStringBuilder()


  override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: ViewHolder?, position: Int) {
    // for 1 till 9
    if (yourNo  in 1..9) {
        if (yourNo  == 1)
            changeSuperScripts(1, 3, yourNo + "st", holder.textView)
        else if (contestStandingItem.rank == 2)
            changeSuperScripts(1, 3, yourNo + "nd", holder.textView)
        else if (contestStandingItem.rank == 3) {
            changeSuperScripts(1, 3, yourNo + "rd", holder.textView)
        } else
            changeSuperScripts(1, 3, yourNo + "th", holder.textView)
    }

    // for 10 till 19
    else if (yourNo  in 10..19)
        changeSuperScripts(2, 4, yourNo  + "th", holder.textView)


    // for 20 till 99
    else if(yourNo  in 20..99) {
         if (yourNo  % 10 == 0)
            changeSuperScripts(2, 4, yourNo  + "th", holder.textView)
        else if (yourNo  % 10 == 1)
            changeSuperScripts(2, 4, yourNo  + "st", holder.textView)
        else if (yourNo  % 10 == 2)
            changeSuperScripts(2, 4, yourNo  + "nd", holder.textView)
        else if (yourNo  % 10 == 3)
            changeSuperScripts(2, 4, yourNo  + "rd", holder.textView)
        else
            changeSuperScripts(2, 4, yourNo  + "th", holder.textView)
    }

    // for 100 till 999
    else if (yourNo  in 100..999){
        if (yourNo  % 10 == 0)
            changeSuperScripts(3, 5, yourNo  + "th", holder.textView)
        else if (yourNo  % 10 == 1)
            changeSuperScripts(3, 5, yourNo  + "st", holder.textView)
        else if (yourNo  % 10 == 2)
            changeSuperScripts(3, 5, yourNo  + "nd", holder.textView)
        else if (yourNo  % 10 == 3)
            changeSuperScripts(3, 5, yourNo  + "rd", holder.textView)
        else
            changeSuperScripts(3, 5, yourNo  + "th", holder.textView)
    }
```

}

// start and end are the indexes from where superscrpits starts and stops

```
     fun changeSuperScripts(start: Int, end: Int, text: String, textView: TextView) {
    stringBuilder.clear()
    stringBuilder.append(text)
    val formatter = OrdinalSuperscriptFormatter.getInstance(stringBuilder)
    formatter.createSuperscriptSpan(start, end, textView)
}
```

// this is a separate class written in java for converting text into superscript, i have made it singleton for using same object everytime(for performance only)

public class OrdinalSuperscriptFormatter {

```
public static OrdinalSuperscriptFormatter ordinalSuperscriptFormatter;

private static final String SUPERSCRIPT_REGEX = "(?<=\\b\\d{0,10})(st|nd|rd|th)(?=\\b)";
private static final Pattern PATTERN = Pattern.compile(SUPERSCRIPT_REGEX);
private static final float PROPORTION = 0.5f;
SuperscriptSpan superscript = new SuperscriptSpan();
RelativeSizeSpan size = new RelativeSizeSpan(PROPORTION);

private final SpannableStringBuilder stringBuilder;

public static OrdinalSuperscriptFormatter getInstance(SpannableStringBuilder stringBuilder){
    if (ordinalSuperscriptFormatter == null) {
        ordinalSuperscriptFormatter = new OrdinalSuperscriptFormatter(stringBuilder);
        return  ordinalSuperscriptFormatter;
    }
    else
        return  ordinalSuperscriptFormatter;
}

public static void refreshInstance(){
    ordinalSuperscriptFormatter = null;
}

private OrdinalSuperscriptFormatter(@NonNull SpannableStringBuilder stringBuilder) {
    this.stringBuilder = stringBuilder;
}

public void createSuperscriptSpan(int start, int end,TextView textView) {
    stringBuilder.setSpan(superscript, start, end, Spanned.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
    stringBuilder.setSpan(size, start, end, Spanned.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
    textView.setText(stringBuilder);
}
```

}

// refreshInstance will call when you are starting your activity or fragmnet again for refreshing your list

```
   override fun onResume() {
    super.onResume()
    OrdinalSuperscriptFormatter.refreshInstance() // must be referesh singleton instance for each history standings
}
```